# Groovy: Could not find matching constructor for 'subclass'

Tags: multithreading, groovy, constructor, subclass

I'm getting the following error:

> Could not find matching constructor for:
>   org.crawler.CrawlerUtils$fetch(org.series.crawler.site.SubSiteA).

I'm trying to use threads. I used threads only one time, and I'm trying to do the same that I did in the other project.

I have:

```js
Class CrawlerUtils {
    public static void crawlSites(List<Site> sites) {
        def pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(MAX_THREADS)
        def ecs = new ExecutorCompletionService<Void>(pool);
        sites.each { ecs.submit(new fetch(it), Void) }
        sites.each { ecs.take().get() }
        pool.shutdown()
    }

    class fetch implements Runnable {
        Site site
        fetch(Site site) {
            this.site = site
        }
        public void run() {
            site.parse()
        }
    }
}
```

I tried these (uglies) approaches:

- Create an Interface (using *ISite site* instead *Site site* inside *fetch* constructor)
- Put a constructor in each subclass inside *fetch* class
- Put a constructor inside each subclass that calls to *super()*

Any idea?

Comment: Have you tried making it a top-level class? I wonder whether it's being an inner class which is the problem. I can't remember whether nested classes in Groovy work the same way as they do in Java...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As `crawlSites` is static the class `Fetch` (should have a capital letter to follow any form of common naming scheme) needs to be static too.

```
static class Fetch implements Runnable
```

I'd use GPars though...  Looks at [this section of the guide](http://www.gpars.org/guide/guide/3.%20Data%20Parallelism.html#3.1.1%20GParsPool)

You should be able to do:

```
GParsPool.withPool {
  sites.eachParallel { site -> site.parse() }
}
```